# Head component from next/head renders into <body> instead of <head>

Tags: next.js, meta-tags

I am setting up a project in nextjs. I would like to add some global meta tags and title to the project. I used the `Head` component from `next/head` in `_app.tsx` but they are being rendered in the body instead of the head both on localhost and when deployed using vercel. I have used next before and can't remember running into this issue.

Here is my `_app.tsx`

```
import { AppProps } from 'next/app' 
import Head from 'next/head' 
import Footer from '../components/footer'
import MobileNavBar from '../components/mobileNavBar'
import NavBar from '../components/navBar'
import '../styles.scss'

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
  return (
    <>
    <Head>
      <html lang="en" />
      <title> Erika's Dog Training </title>
      <meta 
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=5, shrink-to-fit=no"
        name="viewport"
      ></meta>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js"></script> 
    </Head>
    <MobileNavBar />
    <NavBar />
    <Component {...pageProps} />
    <Footer />
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

So the meta tag and title here are showing up on the page, but at the top of the `<body>` tag instead of in `<head>`

Comment: `lang="en"` should be set in the `<Html>` component in `_document`. Remove it from `_app`.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with next: "11.1.2". Removing `<html lang="en" />` fixed the problem. I added the lang value back using: (https://melvingeorge.me/blog/set-html-lang-attribute-in-nextjs)

```
/* next.config.js  */
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ["en"],
    defaultLocale: "en",
  },
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider the structure of [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document) example from the nextjs documentation.

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    return { ...initialProps }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}

export default MyDocument
```

The main differences that I see, is that in the documentation they place both *`head`* and *`body`* as **siblings** within `<Html>` tags. I suspect that is your problem. I would also remove the empty `<>` and `</>` tags.

You have the line: `<html lang="en" />` Inside the Head tag. This is going to make it challenging for next to generate the correct html as the `html` tag is generally above both `Head` and `body` tags.

Answer (score 1):

Place `<html lang="XX"/>` as the last child of `<Head>`.

Example:

```html
<Head>
  <title> Erika's Dog Training</title>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=5, shrink-to-fit=no" name="viewport" />
  <html lang="en" />
</Head>
```